# Flutter web Google Map view not showing

Tags: google-maps, web, flutter

I am making a cross plaform application, it will run on web, android and iOS. I have started testing on web and when I load a Google Map I get the error

`Error: PlatformException(Unregistered factory, No factory registered for viewtype 'plugins.flutter.io/google_maps', null)`

I have already generated a proper API key on [Google Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/overview) and activated all the necessary [APIs & Services](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard?show=all). That includes *Maps Javascript API*. As seen here
[image]    here   [image: image2]  and here    [image: image3]

I have also not restricted the API key for testing purposes.
I don't know if it works on Android or iOS yet.

**My question is, why is this happening? And what solution can I use?**